# Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel

I have condition in Controller with checks the value in database and based on this value is redirecting user to different login pages

```
public function getLogin() 
{               
    $login = DB::table('login')->pluck('login');
    //var_dump($login);
    if ($login == 1) {
        return View::make('users.login');
    } else { 
        return View::make('users.login1');  
    }        
}
```

When I go to login page I've got this error

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

When I `var_dump($login);` I get

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#304 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: do you want to check if all the values in the collection is 1 or you want to check if it has at least 1 item in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this :

```
public function getLogin() 
{               
    $login = DB::table('login')->pluck('login');
    //var_dump($login);
    if ($login->count() == 1) {
        return View::make('users.login');
    } else { 
        return View::make('users.login1');  
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Peter You wrote this works for you and then deleted the comment. This can't work for you Peter, because if collection has 2, 3, 4... items, `$login->count() == 1` will return `false`.

Comment: One issue with this answer is that it counts the number of items in the collection, is it true that the OP wants to check the value in the field and not the count?

Comment: Ithink @Peter wants to count the numbers of records in `login` table, if it's if it's just one he will return 'users.login' view, and if it's more than one he will return 'users.login1' !! am i right @Peter ?

Comment: Current configuration - yes. In future will check `$login->count() == 1`, `$login->count() == 2` .. etc with if,elseif,elfe. is this still going to work?

Comment: @Peter so you actually want to know collection have just one item or not one? Then why in comments you said that you have different values `0, 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: I'm now confused of the collection, values etc. Currently I have two possibilities: `0` and `1`. But there would be more soon `2` and `3`

Comment: There will be no problem @Peter , as i said earlier that `$login->count()` will return the number of records in `login` table, So it will work for all cases `2`, `3` ....

Answer (score 1):

$login is a collection, you get all the values of table login with your query. if you want this create a for loop and have your if statement inside.

for example :

```
foreach ($login as $val) {
    if ($val== 1) {
         return View::make('users.login');
    } else { 
        return View::make('users.login1');  
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isEmpty()` or `count()` here, for example:

```
if (!$login->isEmpty())
if (count($login) > 0)
if ($login->count() > 0)
```

Comment: `isEmpty()` and `empty()` will not work because will never be empty. `count()` is working great like in @maraboc answer

Comment: @Peter I've just tested `isEmpty()` and it works as expected. `empty()` will not work here.

Comment: But I have different values there `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`. In this case if value is `2` and I check if `if (!$login->isEmpty())` how I will know that is `2` and will redirect user?

Comment: @Peter so, you're actually want to check if `$login` collection has value 1? In this case, you should do something like this `$login = DB::table('login')->find(1); if (!is_null($login))`

Comment: I need also the column `->pluck('login')`. Sorry I'm just new and don't understand it very well yet.

Comment: @Peter if you want to get values and then check if there are any values, use `isEmpty()` or `count()`. But Maraboc's answer is wrong, you should use `count()` as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: Last question, you mean like this `if (count($login) > 0)` and why his answer is wrong if is work? Can cause problems?

Comment: @Peter it's working because now your query returns one item. As you said before, your query can return 0, 1, 2, 3 values. In this case `count($login)` will return 4 and `$count($login) == 1` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Its just simple in this case, You can use [0] with login to access it as int.

```
 public function getLogin() 
{               
    $login = DB::table('login')->pluck('login');
    //var_dump($login);
    if ($login[0] == 1) {
        return View::make('users.login');
    } else { 
        return View::make('users.login1');  
    }        
}
```